# Remove sprite from screen cocos2d iphone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

I have a game that I wrote. I am about ready to call it finished but I found a bug. Basically the game gets slower as the longer you play. My guess is this is due to sprites that are still being drawn off screen. I will paste the code below but basically the sprite is created in the "addNewBall" method. In this method it is added to an array which calculates its motion. After the ball reaches a position where it is off the screen it is removed from the array which causes it to stop moving but it is still being "drawn" off screen. How do I remove the sprite so the processor no longer calculates it. Thanks in advance for your help!

Tanner

Code:

```
-(void) addNewBall {
    NumberOfBalls = NumberOfBalls + 1;  

    int RandomXPosition = (arc4random() % 240) + 40;
    NSString *BallFileString = @"OrangeBall.png";

    switch (arc4random() % 5) {
        case 1:
            BallFileString = @"OrangeBall.png";
            break;
            case 2:
                BallFileString = @"GreenBall.png";
                break;
            case 3:
                BallFileString = @"YellowBall.png";
                break;
            case 4:
                BallFileString = @"PinkBall.png";
                break;
            case 0:
                BallFileString = @"BlueBall.png";
                break;
    }


    Ball = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:BallFileString];
    Ball.position = ccp(RandomXPosition, 520);

    BallIsMoving = YES;
    [self addChild:Ball z:10];
    [AllObjectsArray_ addObject:Ball];
    [BallArray_ addObject:Ball];

}


//And here is where it is removed...


if (Ball.position.y <= -100) {

[BallArray_ removeObject: Ball];
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You seem to be missing some conditions in your removal method.  Don't you also want to remove the ball if its y position is greater than the screen height, or if its x position is off-screen?  At any rate, in the same place that you're removing the ball from the array, you should add:

```
[self removeChild:Ball cleanup: YES]
```

I should also point out that your `BallArray` is probably redundant, since you're adding all the balls to another node anyway.  If the only children of that node are `Ball`s, you can get the array of balls using its `children` property.  In this case, the child array would be: `self.children` (See  http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/api-ref/latest-stable/interface_c_c_node.html#a5e739ecda0c314283a89ac389dfca2fa for more info.)

If you have non-Ball children on the same node, you might want to add an intermediate node to simplify the design so that you can use one less array.

Comment: no, i have many children in that node, and the ones that are to behave the same are in the same array. Thanks for you help!!

Comment: Glad to be of help.  If your problem is resolved, you should mark this answer as accepted for the benefit of future readers :)

Answer (score 3):

You said you are removing the objects from the arrays, but you didn't mention that you are also removing the sprite from the parent CCNode.

Check the methods from CCNode to remove childs: http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/api-ref/latest-stable/interface_c_c_node.html#a0d4e615f688458c74001acf10f0ae011

You could use:

```
[Ball removeFromParentAndCleanup:YES];
```

This will remove the ball from it's parent CCNode and will remove all actions and callbacks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify your sprite,and you can use this following line..
    [self removeChild:Ball cleanup: YES]